# Why we can instantiate non-exist variable using $this

Tags: php

Why we can instantiate non-exist variable? What's the different when declare all properties on class and then assign value to it.

```
class hello {

    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function set($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function get() {
        return $this->db;
    }

}
```

Comment: thats the freedom of php. It is not very clean but it works. Thats the difference between php and other strict type-save languages like java or c#.

Comment: I think it's made for fault-tolerance reasons. We can kill people, but we obey the law.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't quite the same as using a non-existent variable - a non-existent variable will raise a notice in PHP. In your case, `$this` already exists, so setting a property on it just quietly creates a `public` property for your object. It's rather like an array that you add a new key-value pair to - you wouldn't expect that to raise a notice either.

If you know beforehand what properties you need, then yes, do declare them explicitly. In this case, you would probably want this to be `protected`, which you don't get if you don't declare. (Often people use `private` here, which means that a child class cannot access the property - though that's okay if you want to force descendants to use the getter).

The flexibility to add properties to objects can be useful if you don't know in advance what properties you'll want to store. For example, some [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)s use one class for all tables, and an instance of that class is used to store the column-value pairs for a row.